# Form Data Returning Null in LocalStorage - LocalStorage Undefined Error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage

I am working on adding bookings to an array in `localStorage` which I finally have working. It will add to the correct area of the storage, however it is returning a value of `null`. My errors are saying that `localStorage` is not defined, nor is `window` or `document`?

I am trying to basically initialise an empty array to add information to, which is working, but it is adding null to the array each time. I think that I have maybe got something in the wrong place or haven't defined something but can't figure out where the issue is. I didn't need to initialise localStorage previously and it worked (to an extent)? I have read a few SO answers but most are for React or Native and aren't of use to me.

Can anyone help me understand where I've went wrong?

```
bookings = []; 

$("#submit").click(function () {

    var bookings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookings')) || [];
    var newBooking = document.getElementsByTagName('input').value;

    bookings.push(newBooking)

    var json = JSON.stringify(bookings);
    window.localStorage.setItem("bookings", json);
});
```

HTML form

```
 <form id="regForm" name="regForm" onsubmit="return setAction(this)" class="col-sm-6">

        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" required>
            <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" required>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>

    </form>
```

I want to get elements by input as I will have more fields in my form in the future.

```js
bookings = []; 

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function () {

    var bookings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookings')) || [];
    var newBooking = document.getElementsByTagName('input').value;

    bookings.push(newBooking)

    var json = JSON.stringify(bookings);
    window.localStorage.setItem("bookings", json);
});
```

```html
<form id="regForm" name="regForm" onsubmit="return false" class="col-sm-6">

        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" required>
            <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" required>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: Which line are you having your error at? What is the exact error message?

Comment: Basically from the beginning, 3, 5, 6 and 11? Errors are '$ is undefined', 'localStorage is not defined', 'document is not defined', 'window is not defined', 'setAction is defined but never used' - the last error is in reference to the form action.

Comment: You are calling `.value` on the results of `getElementsByTagName` which is a collection, not an individual input element. I would recommend using `querySelectorAll` first of all to avoid the complications of a live `HTMLCollection`, but since you are looking to store all the results you should look into `serialize` on the `form`.

Comment: @pilchard that makes sense, I wasn't sure of the right method to use to retrieve the input data, I'll have a go!

Comment: SerializeArray worked! I had that in previous code but it wasn't working, now works great! Thanks for your help! Deadline is in a few days and I was starting to panic.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with getting the input elements, after using `serializeArray` method the data stored correctly, thank you to the person in the comments.

```
 var bookings = []; 

 $("#submit").click(function () {

    bookings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookings')) || [];
    var newBooking = $("#regForm").serializeArray();
    //var newBooking = document.querySelectorAll('input').value;

    bookings.push(newBooking)

    var json = JSON.stringify(bookings);
    window.localStorage.setItem("bookings", json);
 });
```

Posting if anyone else is in need of this solution.